# Pytorch in-place concatenation and conversion to tensor from numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Suppose I have a list of tensors of the same size which could be concatenated along a dimension, say 0. Do any of the commands torch.cat or torch.stack or any numpy commands do the concatenation in-place? Also, if I want to convert a numpy ndarray to tensor. If I do the following, are two copies existing in the memory at any given time? I am dealing with a massive dataset so big only one copy of it can exist in the memory at any given time.

```
# initially data is a huge ndarray
data = torch.Tensor(data)
```

Comment: I don't know about pytorch, but numpy arrays are contiguous in memory. That sounds incompatible with "in-place concatenation". Ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html

Comment: Makes sense. The specific case I am looking for is the case where I have a large tensor to which an incoming single, small tensor is to be concatenated/ stacked. In this case, if the larger tensor stays in-place and can be extended (probably using some non-contiguous memory) without the need to make a second copy of it.

Comment: If your dataset is so big that it hardly fits your RAM, you definitely will not be able create in-memory NN to consume it at one shot. So you will have to use mini-batches anyway. You will have to augment each mini-batch, and this will not become a big memory hit. Also, this will allow you not hold the whole dataset in the memory. See documentation on `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`

Answer (score -1):

From your comment, assuming that:

1. you want to do something in the spirit of: `B = A + a + b + ... + z` where `+` represents concatenation along a compatible axis, `B` and `A` are huge and `a`, `b`, etc., are comparatively small, and
2. you can predict a reasonnable upper bound for the size of `B`

I would allocate beforehand a huge array for `B` using `np.empty`, and I would fill-in this array directly with your data as needed.